Base clock (frequency) setting is required in Ubuntu 20.04

I'm currently using ubuntu 20.04 on an HPE DL380 Gen10 server. The CPU is using Xeon 4216. The problem is that the CPU in question has a base clock of 2.1GHz.
When checking with Turbostat or cat /proc/cpuinfo, one core body is connected at approximately 800MHz to 1.2GHz.
Checking the test servers used by CentOS, etc. have Olympic verification at 2.1 GHz.
BIOS settings are similar. Even if you set cpufreq, cpupower, etc. in your OS, you're asking it to keep the default clock engaged like Centos. I would like to inquire as to how to access the fixed Base Clock.
What's even more unusual is that the same Ubuntu 20.04 and CPU are used, but the kubernetes service is operated and the base clock of the server is confirmed to be 2.1 GHz, which is inconvenient, and other servers are confirmed because they have clocks. Similarly, BIOS and OS settings are the same.
Cleaning up the environment explains it.
leaf condition ubuntu 20.04 & openstack server: 800MHz~1.2GHz centos 7.9 & openstack server: 2.1GHz ubuntu 20.04 & Kubernetes server: 2.1GHz
BIOS & OS settings are the same. Only the service and OS are different.
I would like to play around with the reason or inquire as to whether there is a way to access the Base Clock so that the OS, etc. can handle the Base Clock. As detailed, tuned, cpufreq, cpupower, etc. were not possible.
thank you

Welcome to the site. Please don't post screenshots of console output. They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.
